# Como configurar o procfile do heroku para achar o caminha da aplicação que não esta na raiz do projeto?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, deploy, heroku

Tenho uma aplicação springboot no repositório do git com a seguinte configuração:

```
/api 
.gitignore 
Procfile 
README.md
```

Porem quando tento fazer o deloy no heroku recebo o seguinte erro:

```
!     No default language could be detected for this app.
        HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application 
        automatically.
        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
!     Push failed
```

A configuração que tenho no aquivo Procfile esta dessa forma:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar api/target/MoneyCtrl-0.0.1.jar --server.port=$PORT
```

Alguém sabe como posso configurar o path para o heroku achar a aplicação dentro da pasta /api ?